# How can I make the inline navigation bar transparent before scrolling in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, uinavigationbar, ios13, ios14

I'm want to make the inline navigation bar transparent so it matches the view background but only before scrolling. Once you scroll I would like to use the default navigation background color, just as the large nav bar but with the inline.

Here is an example in the Apple Reminders app (iOS14):

[image]

I tried with this init but it also changes the nav bar background when scrolling.

```
init() {
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = .clear
    UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
    UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
    UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
}
```

Comment: is this a scroll view?

Comment: I think, that is a list but I'm not sure, it's the new reminder view from the Apple Reminders app in iOS14. But it shouldn't matter if you use a Scroll View or a List.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a scrollView add a delegate to the scrollView

```
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    self.stoppedScrolling()
}

func scrollViewDidEndDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {
    if !decelerate {
        self.stoppedScrolling()
    }
}

func stoppedScrolling() {
    println("Scroll finished")
    // Do functionality here to change navbar apperance
}
```

There are other scroll view functions that might help you better than the ones above

Comment: This solution only works for UIKit apps, not SwiftUI.